# Deploy NextJS to IIS Window server

Tags: reactjs, iis, next.js

```
I had a project with NextJS
And I want to deploy to IIS Window
So I have some issues when deploying
The video I followed : 
     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLsx0iraA-Y&t=1s
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqtrl.png)
my `web.config` file is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etslU.png)

```
server.js :
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqXpb.png)

Comment: could you try to assign iis_iusr and iusr permission to the application root folder

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Yeah. Thanks for your reply. I just removed nvm and install nodejs again.I worked fine. Love you so much

Comment: I resolved this issue. Could anyone help me close that?

Comment: you can post the solution and mark as answer